# htaccess redirection in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following code in my `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /annsenglishmediumschool
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} shops.annsenglishmediumschool.com
    RewriteRule .* http://annsenglishmediumschool.com/index.php/shops [L]    
</IfModule>
```

This works fine , but how can i make "shops" as a variable here ? means whatever we type in the place of "`shops`" should come after `http://annsenglishmediumschool.com/index.php/`  thanks in advance .

**EDIT :**
after edit my `.htaccess` looks like this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /annsenglishmediumschool
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.annsenglishmediumschool\.com$
    RewriteRule .* http://annsenglishmediumschool.com/index.php/%1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem is that it now takes only 'www' to the right as annsenglishmediumschool.com/index.php/www ,and no other string ,any help is greatly thanked

Comment: How is CodeIgniter related to this?

Comment: IN codeigniter i want to catch that variable types before the sitename ,thats what i mean ,thats is (anystring).mysite.com to mysite.com/mycontroller/myaction/(anystring)

Comment: Well, this is `.htaccess`, the problem is here, and your CodeIgniter PHP part is (probably) working. You were wondering what you should put in the _.htaccess_, not the _PHP_ to get this working.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the part of the domain name you're interested in as `%1` and use it in the [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.annsenglishmediumschool\.com$
RewriteRule .* http://annsenglishmediumschool.com/index.php/%1 [R,L]
```

If the host does not start with `www.`, this grabs the first part of the domain `(.+?)` and puts it in the `RewriteRule` as `%1`.

When everything works as you expect, you can change `R` to `R=301`.

*Never* test with `301` enabled, see this answer
[Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542)
for details.

Comment: when i types www.annsenglishmediumschool.com its taking the right as : annsenglishmediumschool.com/index.php/www and no other string is taking as when i type shops.annsenglishmediumschool.com its not going as such to  annsenglishmediumschool.com/index.php/shops.This is the problem

Comment: Any solutions .i got stuck

Comment: @Icecreamsandwich Do you want to see the new URL in the browser bar? Or do you want to keep the original URL and just serve some different content?

Comment: I want to  see the the new URL in the browser bar

Comment: @Icecreamsandwich Then you must not only rewrite but also redirect `R`.

Comment: but the problem is ,here its redirecting www also ,and not taking any other strings before sitename .thats when typing www.sitename.com its going to sitename.com/index.php/www

Comment: @Icecreamsandwich Do you want to exclude www.sitename.com from being rewritten? What do you mean with "not taking any other strings before sitename"? Can you provide an example and what happens when you enter this example, e.g. some error message or something else?

Comment: I mean that if i type :www.sitename.com its going to sitename.com/index.php/www ,its not that i want , i needed it as when type : subdomain.sitename.com then it should go to sitename.com/index.php/subdmain

Comment: @Icecreamsandwich Then you must exclude `www.` with a `RewriteCond`. The rule already does the subdomain part. Please see updated answer.

Comment: okay ,let me check ,but it was not going as explected : when i type subdomain.domain.com its not going to domain.com/index.php/subdomain ,it shows website not found

Comment: @Icecreamsandwich Then your server is not setup to serve `subdomain.domain.com`. The domain name must point to your webserver and the main config or virtual host config must have an appropriate [`ServerName`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servername) or [`ServerAlias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serveralias).

Comment: How to set up as "The domain name must point to your webserver", i dont know ,any help is appreciated,the manual creation of subdomains in cpanel wont work

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing two things. You can pass parameter directly to your controller to get the "shop" as variable.

for example :

```
index($variable){

echo $variable;

}
```

//It will echo $variable(shop this time) at yoursite.com/index.php/shop

Comment: but its like subdomain , if user types subdomain.mysite.com then i want to catch the subdomain name in my controller ,now its static and accepts only "shops"